# Mahalanobis vs centering / standard deviations

Tags: standard-deviation, normalization, centering, mahalanobis

Is there a difference whether to use a Mahalanobis distance or transform the data via centering (and normalization) when you are interested in calculating distances?
This means, if you are interested in the distance between point 1 and point 2 and when you use

1. the Mahalanobis distance or
2. the Euclidean distance after centering and normalizing,

would both 1) and 2) yield something differently or the same?

**Mahalanobis**

[image: img1]

**Centering & Normalization**
[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: Those pictures look different to me!

Comment: because they are?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question, then. Just by looking at pictures, you see there is a difference.

Comment: Maybe you mean/see a different difference than I do ^^ My question is as above stated, basically, if there is a difference whether to calculate the distance by Mahalanobis or to center/normalize the data and use e.g. Euclidean then. Tbh, I'm not sure whether this or these images imply a difference or if they are the same? I mean I can visually see that they are different but would a distance measure yield something different? Maybe I should add this in the question, indeed..